# Lua: How can i reach a class variable from another class?

Tags: lua

I have this object in a file 'tracking.lua', which is:

```
local trackingObject = Object3D(scene:getObjectByName("Tracking_Object"))
```

In the file 'MotionDetection.lua', I have this:

```
for i,v in ipairs(zone) do
    zoneDetection[i] = chaneledHistory:testRegion2D(v, moveRatio);
    if zoneDetection[i] then 
        zoneDet[i] = 1
        LOG('zone '..i..' detected')
    end
end
```

In 'MotionDetection.lua', if `i` is 1, I want to set `trackingObject`'s status in 'tracking.lua' to `true`:

```
trackingObject:setVisible(true)
```

if `i` is 2, I want to set `trackingObject`'s status in 'tracking.lua' to `false`:

```
trackingObject:setVisible(false)
```

How can I reach `trackingObject` in 'tracking.lua' from 'MotionDetection.lua'?

Comment: actually it's not a class because I don't have any function, It's two lua file.................. hope someone can help me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `trackingObject` is set as local in `tracking.lua` (`local trackingObject = Object3D...`), there is nothing you can do to access that variable from `MotionDetection.lua`. You do have a couple of options that allow you to make that object available: you can either switch to using a [global variable](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.2.html) in this case, or return a table/object as the results of `tracking.lua`, which will allow other modules that load `tracking.lua` (for example, using `require 'tracking'`) get access to those values (see [Lua manual for require](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require)).